# Semantic/Contextual Categorization API

Tags: semantic-web

I'm working on a project that requires categorizing content of a given URL. Basically, I want to pass a URL to this API and it will return the category or list of categories based on its content. I think Textwise.com may have this service. Are there other similar services out there?

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/) from Reuters is another such system.

You can also roll your own using open source systems like [Gate](http://gate.ac.uk/) which will allow you to avoid things like API limits but may require you to train your system appropriately.

Comment: thanks RobV! I'll check 'em out and post back.

Comment: Have any of you had luck getting OpenCalais to work? I'm having a time getting around the API. I'll look into Gate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimilarWeb Categorization API](https://developer.similarweb.com/website_categorization_API).

The API returns a given domain's category based on content analysis and machine learning in XML or JSON.

Some implementation of a similar usage can be found [here](https://github.com/SimilarWeb/api-tools).

Also:

```
function api_category(URL, KEY) {

  var apiurl = "http://api.similarweb.com/Site/"
  + URL
  + "/v2/category?Format=JSON&UserKey="
  + KEY;

  var fetch_category = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiurl);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);

      var data  =  JSON.parse(fetch_category);
      return data.Category.replace(/_/g, " "); // convert underscores to spaces 
    }
```

Comment: It's more useful if you post the useful code on StackOverflow. Link-only answers can change and become obsolete in the future.

Answer (score -1):

[CommTouch](http://www.commtouch.com/url-miscat/) is also one of the option.

Answer (score -1):

zvelo.com is also an option, if it's for a commercial offering. zvelo has been a Leading provider of content + context categorization services for years. Unmatched URL database.